# NamedTuple: Creating Inner class from Outer.Inner name creates warning (in PyCharm)

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Consider this code

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class Outer:
    class Inner(NamedTuple):
        a: int
        b: int

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = Outer.Inner(2, 1)  # generates warning
        self.y = self.Inner(2, 1)  # doesn't generate warning


class Foo(NamedTuple):
    c: int
    d: int


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Outer.Inner(2, 1)  # generates warning as well.
    z = Outer().Inner(2, 1)  # doesn't generate warning.

    bar = Foo(2, 1)  # doesn't generate warning.
```

while I'm perfectly happy with using `self.Inner` inside `Outer` to create an instance of `inner` I see no point of creating an implicit instance of `Outer` in code outside of `Outer`, such as `__main__` to create an instance of `Inner`. Especially since both work. So where does this warning come from?

```
Calling a method by class using an instance of a different class

This inspection checks for calls of a method by class while passing an instance of a different class as self parameter:
  foo = Foo()
  Bar.baz(foo, *more)
Sometimes this may be intentional and correct. But when unintentional, this leads to subtle bugs.
```

Comment: The real question here is "do you have to use nested classes"

Comment: @DeepSpace no it's not. It doesn't matter if it's good practice or not, it is just about correct syntax. Also off topic - so far any argument against the use of nested classes has failed to convince me.

Comment: in that case the warning you quoted explains it all

Comment: You clearly don't understand the issue here. The warning incorrectly thinks that `Outer.Inner()` expects Outer as first argument. Which it doesn't. Also even if that WERE the case, it would be inconsistent with `Outer().Inner()` or `self.Inner()`, right?